# Cannot concert type’UITextField’ to expected argument type ‘String’

Tags: swift, firebase, variables, uitextfield, firebase-authentication

So I’m really struggling with this and I don’t know why tbh.

I tried different ways of forcing my username (email address) to String from a text field. I just can’t get the damn thing to convert or to accept input as a String. Ridiculously been trying for nearly a whole day to get this in the meantime I wrote the rest of my Login func but this is stopping it from working or letting me see other errors.

`Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username, password: password, completion: { user,` error in

My text field is called username. I’ve tried converting (String(username)), as String, and such, I’ve tried creating var and let to make it String but this only produces more errors I’m thinking the thing is corrupt!

Please help.

Comment: So you want the input to be only letters, not numbers ? (not even numbers in string format?)

Comment: I want it to be an email address as the user is going to register with email and this will become a sort of unique username.

Comment: Ok. But you want to check if the input is email when the user click on a button or something, right? you cannot check it as they are typing because it will show error until the user enters @domain.com

Comment: Kind of I want the user to enter an email address to use as username. The UITextField won’t let me call it to the login function at all without error. So to avoid the error I’ve been trying to get text as String. This isn’t even in the button press to login or signup it’s just building the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UITextField` named `username` you get the text from the textfield by: `username.text`, which returns a `String?`.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text

Comment: So when I add .text to the username in the login func I get another error. “Value of optional type ‘String?’ not unwrapped; did you mean to use ‘!’ or ‘?’?”

Comment: If you want to pass a `String` instead of a `String?` you can do: `username.text ?? ""`, then you will use an empty string if you get `nil` from `uesrname.text`.

Comment: When I add either ! or ? It gives me a new error “Cannot concert type UITextField to expected arguement type ‘String’l

Comment: I’ve read some posts on this which refer me to developer.apple but that  is ambiguous and doesn’t solve my problem here.

Comment: Then you haven't called `text` on the UITextField. You must add more code to the question if I should help be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
func performLogin() {
   //Logging In
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username, password: password, completion: { user, error in
         if (error != nil){
            errorLabel = error1 //"There has been an Error " + "No User Found"
            //Could Not Login, Attempt to Create user

            //Creating Account
            Auth.auth().createUserWithEmail(self.username, password: self.password!, completion: { user, error in
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `UITextField` is not a `String` but it does have a value that is a string called `text`. To get this just change your code

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username.text, password: password.text, completion: { user,...
```

However, as you have mentioned `text` is an optional String which is why you are receiving an error, the function is expecting an explicit String

The text value of a `UITextField` is optional, meaning that you can guarantee that it's value will not be nil. You should read more on the basics of Swift and optional vs explicit but here is a simple solution.

Before passing your variables in the sign-in you can unwrap them using a `guard` statement

```
guard let usernameString = username.text else {
   // Handle no username, show an alert etc
   return
}

guard let passwordString = password.text else {
   // Handle no password, show an alert etc
   return
}

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: usernameString, password: passwordString, completion: { user,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I've been building my app in Firebase, I came across the same problem with my text fields etc when trying to create a user with an email. I just built it into a function and it works like a dream...

```
 func signIn() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
        print(user?.uid)
        if error != nil {
            self.displayAlert(title: "Error", message: (error!.localizedDescription))
        } else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let loggedInView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Today")
            self.present(loggedInView, animated: true,  completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

its a nice easy way to do it.

Hope that helps.